# Add a custom checkout multi-select field and update order meta in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm struggling with one custom woocommerce checkout form's **multi-select field**.

I created custom multislect field via function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) { 
     $fields['billing']['_myfield'] = array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'id' => '_myfield',
        'label'     => __('My Field', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'options'       => [
            'key1'  => __('First Item', 'woocommerce'),
            'key2'  => __('Second Item', 'woocommerce'),
            'key3'  => __('Third Item', 'woocommerce'),
            'key4'  => __('Fourth Item', 'woocommerce')
        ]
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

note, that woocommerce function `custom_override_checkout_fields` isn't capable to create a custom multi-select field, so here we have simple select field.

I decided to use **jQuery** to add the multiple missing attribute this way:

```
$('#_myfield').attr('multiple', 'multiple');
```

So now I have multiselect field, which looks like:

```
<select name="_myfield" id="_myfield" class="select " data-placeholder="" multiple="multiple">...</select>
```

**Problem is**, that order meta value isn't updating properly, it show everytime only one value, not an array of values if person select more than one option.

I'm using this function to update order's meta value:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id) {
   update_post_meta($order_id, '_myfield', $_POST['_myfield'] );
}
```

Any help ?

Maybe there's is better solution to create multi-select field in checkout's billing section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct way to make a custom multi-select checkout field and to grab the selected values in the order meta data.

All jQuery code is included in the function, so you will have to remove yours.

I have added a hidden input field, where I grab in it the selected values with jQuery. When the order is placed, I save the data from this hidden input field.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_checkout_fields', 30, 1 );
function custom_checkout_fields ( $fields ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    $fields['billing']['multi_my_field'] = array(
        'label'        => __('My Field', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'        => true,
        'autocomplete' => false,
        'type'         => 'select',
        'options'      => array(
            'key1'  => __('First Item', $domain),
            'key2'  => __('Second Item', $domain),
            'key3'  => __('Third Item', $domain),
            'key4'  => __('Fourth Item', $domain),
        ),
    );
    ?>
    <input type="hidden"  name="billing_my_field" id="billing_my_field" value="0">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            var a = 'select[name="multi_my_field"]',
                b = 'input[name="billing_my_field"]';
            $(a).attr('multiple', 'multiple');
            $(a).change( function(){
                $(b).val($(this).val());
            })
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'hidden_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 30, 1 );
function hidden_checkout_field_update_order_meta ( $order_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['billing_my_field'] ) )
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_my_field', esc_attr( $_POST['billing_my_field'] ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works